# How do I append an a tag to a ul with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’m creating a navbar, and I’m wanting an if statement that, when true, my `<a>` tag will get wrapped with `<li>` and append to my `<ul>` to join the other `<li>` tags and behave in the same way. I could only get so far as to append my `<a>` to my `<ul>`, but when I tried to wrap `<li>` tags around it, it hit me with an error. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Foo</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <a class="insta-link" target="_blank" 
href="https://www.instagram.com/foo"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>foo</a>
            <ul class="nav-items">
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
```

Comment: Hey @Calor1.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get the answers you seek, it will help to include the HTML and Javascript you're working with, what you have tried as far as Javascript, what happens, and you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the innerHTML of a ul element like this to add the li's and a's you want conditionally. I'm using one li but you could obviously add as many as you want...

javascript:

```
if($(window).width <= [insert desired width to append the a tag here]) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `
        <li><a class="insta-link" href="www.somesite.com">true condition met</a></li>
    `;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = `
        <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    `;
}
```

html:

```
 <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Could you please have another look, I couldn't get your method to work. I've added the code to hopefully provide more clarity of my problem. I'm trying to get the `<a>` with the class of "insta-link" to simply join the existing list of `<li>`s, when the width of the browser reaches a certain width. Thanks

Comment: @Calor1 I just updated the if statement's condition. If you want to add the link when the browser is less than or equal to a certain width, the condition I listed just needs whatever that width is inserted into the square brackets as shown above. If it needs to be only added when the browser is greater than or equal to that width, then swap the "<=" to ">=". Also, this is a jQuery method, so make sure you are including the jQuery CDN from here: https://code.jquery.com/ . I recommend getting the 3.x minified version. Copy/paste that in your head tag

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said, but the problem is now, the `<a>` tag is where it was, but it's also in the list, all the time, not just when the desired width is met

Comment: @Calor1 in the else statement, did you write out all the li’s you would want when the screen’s width is out of the bounds you want? Without the insta-link a tag in the else statement?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it's a problem with my explanation, or the condition of the statement, but no ones solution is working. Thanks anyway though

Comment: @Calor1 these are the li's you want to always show right? <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>

Comment: Yeah that's right. Then when I expand the width of the browser window, I want the `<a>` tag to join on the left-hand-side

Comment: @Calor1 you just want it to be beside the Home link to its left?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it with pure JavaScript:

```
if ( true ) {
    list = document.createElement("li"); //creates an <li></li> tag
    link = document.getElementById("idOfaTag"); //fetch the <a> tag from the document and assign to link
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link); //this will remove the existing <a> tag 
    list.appendChild(link); // This is how you wrap <li> around <a>
    document.getElementById("idOfulTag").appendChild(list); // Appends <li> containing <a>as child to your <ul> with other <li> tags
}
```

Classes and IDs work differently. ID is unique to every single element.So assign an ID for your `<a>` tag with class `insta-link`. And use that ID in setting the `link` variable. Also, assign an id for your `<ul>` .
Using IDs would be preferable when you're dealing with a unique element. Same classes can be assigned to multiple elements in the same page. When you want to apply the same change for multiple elements, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Element**s** with an s because multiple elements!

Comment: Could you please have another look, I couldn't get your method to work. I've added the code to hopefully provide more clarity of my problem. I'm trying to get the `<a>` with the class of "insta-link" to simply join the existing list of `<li>`s, when the width of the browser reaches a certain width. Thanks

Comment: Since you've posted the source code, I've gotten more context and have made edits to my code. Try this and let me know the outcome :)

Comment: Also if further help is needed, it'd be great if you post your JS source code too.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. Nor is anyone else's solution so there must be something wrong with my explanation or with the condition of the if statement. Thanks for your contribution, though

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
list.innerHTML += `<li id="instaLi"></li>`
instaLi.appendChild(insta);
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="insta" class="insta-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/foo"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>foo</a>
  <ul id="list" class="nav-items">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you please have another look, I couldn't get your method to work. I've added the code to hopefully provide more clarity of my problem. I'm trying to get the `<a>` with the class of "insta-link" to simply join the existing list of `<li>`s, when the width of the browser reaches a certain width. Thanks